# PowerShell to match multiple lines with regex pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

I write a Powershell script and regex to search two configs text files to find matches for Management Vlan. For example, each text file has two Management vlan configured as below:

**Config1.txt**

```text
123 MGMT_123_VLAN                  
234 MGMT_VLAN_234
```

**Config2.txt**

```text
890 MGMT_VLAN_890
125 MGMT_VLAN_USERS
```

Below is my script. It has several problems.

First, if I ran the script with the `$Mgmt_vlan = Select-String -Path $File -Pattern $String -AllMatches` then the screen output shows the expected four (4) Mgmt vlan, but in the CSV file output shows as follow

```text
Filename                          Mgmt_vlan
Config1.txt                       System.Object[]
Config2.txt                       System.Object[]
```

I ran the script the output on the console screen shows exactly four (4) Management vlans that I expected, but in the CSV file it did not.  It shows only these vlans

Second, if I ran the script with `$Mgmt_vlan = Select-String -Path $File -Pattern $String | Select -First 1`

Then the CSV shows as follows:

```text
Filename                          Mgmt_vlan
Config1.txt                       123 MGMT_123_VLAN 
Config2.txt                       890 MGMT_VLAN_890
```

The second method `Select -First 1` appears to select only the first match in the file. I tried to change it to `Select -First 2` and then CSV shows column Mgmt_Vlan as `System.Object[]`.

The result output to the screen shows exactly four(4) Mgmt Vlans as expected.

```
$folder = "c:\config_folder"
$files = Get-childitem $folder\*.txt

Function find_management_vlan($Text)
{
    $Vlan = @()
    foreach($file in files) {
        Mgmt_Vlan = Select-String -Path $File -Pattern $Text -AllMatches
        if($Mgmt_Vlan)  # if there is a match
        {
            $Vlan += New-Object -PSObject -Property @{'Filename' = $File; 'Mgmt_vlan' = $Mgmt_vlan}
            $Vlan | Select 'Filename', 'Mgmt_vlan' | export-csv C:\documents\Mgmt_vlan.csv
            $Mgmt_Vlan             # test to see if it shows correct matches on screen and yes it did
        }
        else
        {
            $Vlan += New-Object -PSObject -Property @{'Filename' = $File; 'Mgmt_vlan' = "Mgmt Vlan Not Found"}
            $Vlan | Select 'Filename', 'Mgmt_vlan' | Export-CSV C:\Documents\Mgmt_vlan.csv
        }
     }
 }
 
 find_management_vlan "^\d{1,3}\s.MGMT_"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex correction

First of all, there are a lot of mistakes in this code.
So this is probably not code that you actually used.

Secondly, that pattern will not match your strings, because if you use `"^\d{1,3}\s.MGMT_"` you will match 1-3 numbers, any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ]), any character (except for line terminators) and MGMT_ chars and anything after that. So not really what you want. So in your case you can use for example this: `^\d{1,3}\sMGMT_` or with `\s+` for more than one match.

### Code Correction

1. Now back to your code... You create array $Vlan, that's ok.
2. After that, you tried to get all strings (in your case 2 strings from every file in your directory) and you create PSObject with two complex objects. One is FileInfo from System.IO and second one is an array of strings (String[]) from System. Inside the Export-Csv function `.ToString()` is called on every property of the object being processed. If you call .ToString() on an array (i.e. Mgmt_vlan) you will get `"System.Object[]"`, as per default implementation. So you must have a collection of "flat" objects if you want to make a csv from it.
3. Second big mistake is creating a function with more than one responsibility. In your case your function is responsible for gathering data and after that for exporting data. That's a big no no. So repair your code and move that Export somewhere else. You can use for example something like this (i used get-content, because I like it more, but you can use whatever you want to get your string collection.

   ````
   function Get-ManagementVlans($pattern, $files)
   {
       $Vlans = @()
       foreach ($file in $files)
       {
           $matches = (Get-Content $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8).Where({$_ -imatch $pattern})
           if ($matches)
           {
               $Vlans += $matches | % { New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'Filename' = $File; 'Mgmt_vlan' = $_.Trim()}  }
           }
           else
           {
               $Vlans += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'Filename' = $File; 'Mgmt_vlan' = "Mgmt Vlan Not Found"}
           }
       }

       return $Vlans
   }

   function Export-ManagementVlans($path, $data)
   {
       #do something...
       $data | Select Filename,Mgmt_vlan | Export-Csv "$path\Mgmt_vlan.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
   }

   $folder = "C:\temp\soHelp"
   $files = dir "$folder\*.txt"

   $Vlans = Get-ManagementVlans -pattern "^\d{1,3}\sMGMT_" -files $files
   $Vlans
   Export-ManagementVlans -path $folder -data $Vlans```
   ````

### Summary

But in my opinion in this case is overprogramming to create something like you did. You can easily do it in oneliner (but you didn't have information if the file doesn't include anything). The power of powershell is this:

```
$pattern = "^\d{1,3}\s+MGMT_"
$path = "C:\temp\soHelp\"
dir $path -Filter *.txt -File | Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 | ? {$_ -imatch $pattern} | select @{l="FileName";e={$_.PSChildName}},@{l="Mgmt_vlan";e={$_}} | Export-Csv -Path "$path\Report.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

or with Select-String:

```
dir $path -Filter *.txt -File | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches | select FileName,@{l="Mgmt_vlan";e={$_.Line}} | Export-Csv -Path "$path\Report.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Very appreciate your detailed explanation & pointed out my code prob.  I'm new and learning Python, PS, & Regex by reading books/Google. New to using PSobjects, Export-CSV stores Obj/string. Didn't know its not a good practice that Function should not perform many responsibilities. My work requires me to write PS/Regex to audit ea device's config for comply with network rules. For ea rule, I wrote a function like this code and export-csv and merge all csv at the end. I need to rewrite the script to separate the Export-CSV as you suggested. What was your best method to learn PS and Regex? thx

Comment: @CBLT You're welcome. There are a lot of programming principles (KISS, DRY, SOLID,..) and design patterns. Just read something about it if you are interested. I would recommend you just keep the code simple, maintainable and self-documented. The self-documented aproach gives you hints if your methods or functions are doing "too much". I know that for simple scripts it is not so usable, but you will write your own modules and cmdlets someday and it will pay of later. Maybe you will start with some big OOP language and you will need it.

Comment: @CBLT And the code in my answer is also not right. The functions should be named `Get-ManagementVlansFromFiles` and `Export-ManagementVlansToCsv`. Best way in my opinion is just read, work with code and pay for some course (or see something online, like pluralsight)